# List minimum in Python with None?

Tags: python, list, max, python-2.x, minimum

Is there any clever in-built function or something that will return `1` for the `min()` example below? (I bet there is a solid reason for it not to return anything, but in my particular case I need it to disregard `None` values really bad!)

```
>>> max([None, 1,2])
2
>>> min([None, 1,2])
>>>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`None` is being returned

```
>>> print min([None, 1,2])
None
>>> None < 1
True
```

If you want to return `1` you have to filter the `None` away:

```
>>> L = [None, 1, 2]
>>> min(x for x in L if x is not None)
1
```

Comment: Note that `None` is only returned in Python 2. In Python 3, `min([None, 1, 2])` yields a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`.

Answer (score 9):

using a generator expression:

```
>>> min(value for value in [None,1,2] if value is not None)
1
```

eventually, you may use filter:

```
>>> min(filter(lambda x: x is not None, [None,1,2]))
1
```

Comment: The syntax has nothing python 3. It works in python 2 just fine. 
Using `is` for comparing with `None` as in `value is not None` is prefered to using `==` (or `!=`). The line with `filter` is **wrong**, try putting a 0 in the list and you'll see it will get filtered too, which is not what you want.

Comment: Which is quicker, a list comprehension or a filter?

Comment: @c00kiemonster: They don't do the same thing. a `filter` is **wrong** here, as I pointed in my comment.

Comment: oh i see, when you said filter in your reply, you meant filter through a list comprehension, and not filter as in filter()...

Comment: @nosklo: sorry, i thought generator expressions were introduced in python 3. i already corrected the `is not None`. and you are right the filter was wrong, corrected now...

Comment: now after the edit, the `filter()` version got very very ugly... :P

Comment: @nosklo: i even wrote a worse version: `import functools, operator; min(filter(partial(operator.is_not,None),[None,1,2]))`. with the problem you pointed earlier, there is now nothing to gain using `filter()`. python is missing a function for testing the common case of being None...

Comment: @Adrien Plisson: Please FIX the first line of your answer; you don't use a list comprehension and as mentioned by nosklo "Python 3 syntax" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Make None infinite for min():

```
def noneIsInfinite(value):
    if value is None:
        return float("inf")
    else:
        return value

>>> print min([1,2,None], key=noneIsInfinite)
1
```

Note: this approach works for python 3 as well.